# Update vespa application without removing existing data

Tags: vespa

I want to update my vespa application on docker. I have added some new documents and also change and add some fields in existing documents.Also added java components in updated build. Now I want to deploy updated app on server without removing the existing data from vespa.How can I do this? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/cloudconfig/application-packages.html - use `deploy` to deploy an updated application package. You can do this on a running instance - if there is a need for restart or re-feed, the deploy command will output this